# Integrating infinitesimals dot product

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work, potential-energy, vectors, integration

I just wanted to know why is this possible:

$$\int_{i}^{f}-\frac{dU}{dr}\overrightarrow{e_{r}}\cdot (dr\overrightarrow{e_{r}})=\int_{i}^{f}-dU$$

Could someone help me figure out what is happening with that dot product?

P.S.: Integrating vectors tips are welcome (I'm a first year)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have two vectors in the same direction with the length one ($\vec{e}_r$) they yield 1 when multiplied with each other.
$$
\vec{e}_{r}\cdot (dr\vec{e}_{r})= (\vec{e}_r\cdot \vec{e}_r)dr=dr
$$

So you are left with

$$
\int_{i}^{f}-\frac{dU}{dr}\cdot dr=-(U(f)-U(i))
$$

Here you integrate the derivative of U with respect to r (that is $dU/dr$) with respect to r. So you get the function $U$ itself back. This is a direct conclusion from the [Fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus).

Another way to look at it is by using substitution (which of course uses the fundamental thereom of calculus itself). The formula for this is
$$
\int_a^b f(\phi(t))\cdot\phi'(t) dt=\int_{\phi(a)}^{\phi(b)} f(x) dx
$$

With $f(x)=1$ you get what you want.

In general when calculating integrals with vectors there is not so much of a difference. When the integrand consists of vectors, the result is either a vector or a "normal" function (in the case above the vectors cancel each other in such a way, that you are left with a function). If this is not a case, i.e. your integrand is a vector, then you can integrate each component separately. This is not always the best approach, but in principle it works.

Comment: It makes total sense, and in matter of fact you helped me realize one propertie that I never had thought before $\alpha \vec{v_{1}}\cdot \beta \vec{v_{2}}=\alpha \beta (\vec{v_{1}}\cdot \vec{v_{2}})$. Sounds obvious but it wasn't for me, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome! I think I will edit my answer accordingly to make it absolutely clear.